# Expressjs: How to search correctly with multiple query string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, query-string

I have written a function called filterSearch which is not admin protected that returns resources based on several searches/query parameters. The first search based on status works well but others in the if statements do not work as expected.

This is the route

```
carRouter.get('/car', filterSearch, verifyToken, isAdmin, fetchAllCarAds);
```

These are the respective SQL queries

```
export const statusQuery = 'SELECT * FROM cars WHERE status = $1';
export const statusPriceQuery = 'SELECT * FROM cars WHERE status = $1 AND price >= $2 AND price <= $3';
export const statusManufacturerQuery = 'SELECT * FROM cars WHERE status = $1 manufacturer = $2';
export const bodyTypeQuery = 'SELECT * FROM cars WHERE bodytype = $1';
export const statusStateQuery = 'SELECT * FROM cars WHERE status = $1 AND (state = $2 OR state = $3)';
```

I have used different control statements like else if but it still doesn't work.

```
static async filterSearch(req, res, next) {
    //console.log('req1', typeof req.query);
    if (req.query.status || req.query.bodytype) {
      //console.log('req2', req.query);
      let { status, minprice, maxprice, bodytype, state, manufacturer } = req.query;
      //console.log('req3', typeof bodytype);
      try {
        //status
        status = status.trim().toLowerCase();
        if (status && !minprice && !maxprice) {
          const { rows, rowCount } = await db.query(statusQuery, ['unsold']);
          if (rowCount === 0) {
            return res.status(404).json({
              status: 404,
              error: 'Sorry, this does not exist'
            });
          }
          return res.status(200).json({
            status: 200,
            data: rows
          });
        }

        //status and price
        if (status && minprice && maxprice) {
          minprice = Number(minprice.trim());
          maxprice = Number(maxprice.trim());
          const { rows, rowCount } = await db.query(statusPriceQuery, ['unsold', minprice, maxprice]);
            console.log('row', rowCount);
            if (rowCount === 0) {
              return res.status(404).json({
                status: 404,
                error: 'There is no result for your search now'
              });
            }
            return res.status(200).json({
              status: 200,
              data: rows
            });
          }

        //status and state(new/used)
        if (status && state) {
          state = state.trim().toLowerCase();
          const { rows, rowCount } = await db.query(statusStateQuery, ['unsold', 'new', 'used']);
          if (rowCount === 0) {
            return res.status(404).json({
              status: 404,
              error: 'Search request is unavailable at the moment'
            });
          }
          return res.status(200).json({
            status: 200,
            data: rows
          });
        }

        // status and manufacturer
        if (status && manufacturer) {
          manufacturer = manufacturer.trim().toLowerCase();
          const { rows, rowCount } = await db.query(statusManufacturerQuery, ['unsold', manufacturer]);
          console.log('qui');
            if (rowCount === 0) {
              return res.status(404).json({
                status: 404,
                error: 'Something just happen right now'
              });
            }
            return res.status(200).json({
              status: 200,
              data: rows
            })
          }

        //bodyType
        if (bodytype) {
        //Here I get 'Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined'
          bodytype = bodytype.trim().toLowerCase();
          const { rows , rowCount } = await db.query(bodyTypeQuery, [bodytype]);
          if (rowCount === 0) {
            return res.status(404).json({
              status: 404,
              error: 'your search returned no result'
            });
          }
          return res.status(200).json({
            status: 200,
            data: rows
          });
        }

       return res.status(404).json({
         status: 404,
         error: 'There seems to be an issue with your search'
       });
      } 
      catch(error) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          status: 500,
          error: error.message
        });
      }


    }
    next();
  }
```

- I expect that I should be able to search based on the specified query string if supplied but I get 'Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined when I try to search by 'bodytype'.
- When some query parameters are not present it ought to return 'There seems to be an issue with your search or 404' but it goes ahead to get the all cars which is admin protected.

Comment: when you ```console.log(req.query)``` what it is printing?

Comment: You are trying to read query params, try using ```req.param()```

Comment: @user269867 ```req.query``` prints out its value above and I wasn't dealing ```req.params```. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. All I just had to do was break down the function into bits to accommodate each query search/term supplied.